# buscar hijos (children) con contenido dinamico

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

el problema es que al querer usar el .children en una clase de un div que sea llamado por medio de ajax, no me trae ningún resultado (no me imprime el console.log con la contabilización), es como si no estuviera en la pagina.
¿Ustedes saben como puedo usar el .children pero con contenido que venga dinamico

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var numero=0;
   $(document).on('change', '#edit-field-campus-pro-target-id', function() {

      $('.view-content').children().each(function () {
         numero=numero+1;
         console.log(numero);

    });
});
```

});

agrego html de lo que estoy buscando (no puedo poner todo por el limite de html que me da )

```
<div class="view-content">

    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-odd">


        <div class="field--item">

            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-titulo-imagen-cont paragraph--view-mode--default" id="federal-plus-loan">
                <div class="white">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="column-left border-right flex-center" style="height: 350px;">
                                <div class="content-columns">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                        <div class="text-left">

                                            <div class="field field--name-field-adm-titulo field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">Casas de asistencia del CEMYD </div>

                                            <div class="field field--name-field-adm-descripcion field--item">
                                                <p>Tiene como labor social proporcionar hospedaje a estudiantes mujeres talentosas y con limitantes económicas. Como parte de su filosofía y en apoyo a los valores que el Tec promueve en sus alumnos, el CEMYD enfatiza en la práctica de competencias ciudadanas y desarrollo profesional, así como también crear conciencia de la responsabilidad de retribuir el apoyo recibido por este Club.
                                                </p>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                                <i class="material-icons collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#acordeon2396" href="#acordeon2396" style="color: #C42129"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column-right imagen" style="height: 350px;">
                                <div class="overlay"></div>
                                <div class="content-imagen" style="background:#212121;">

                                    <div class="field field--name-field-adm-imagen field--type-image field--label-hidden field--item">

                                        <img src="/sites/default/files/foto3.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt="FEDERAL PLUS LOAN" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" style="height: 350px;">

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse" id="acordeon2396">

                        <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-cont-tabs paragraph--view-mode--default">
                            <div class="container">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="active" style="border-bottom-width: 54px;">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-caracteristicasplan2396">
                                            CARACTERÍSTICAS
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="border-bottom-width: 54px;">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-beneficiosplan2396">
                                            REQUISITOS
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li style="border-bottom-width: 54px;">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-contactosplan2396">
                                            CONTACTOS
                                        </a>
                                    </li>


                                    <li style="border-bottom-width: 54px; display: none;">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-fechasplan2396">
                                            FECHAS
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="paragraph-caracteristicasplan2396">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                <div class="white">
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                <div class="content-description">
                                                                    <div class="field-content"><ul><li>Apoyo de hospedaje</li>
                                                                    <li>Aplica solo para mujeres</li>
                                                                </ul></div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade " id="paragraph-beneficiosplan2396">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                <div class="white">
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                <div class="content-description">
                                                                    <div class="field-content"><ul><li>Admisión al Tecnológico de Monterrey, Campus Monterrey</li>
                                                                    <li>Demostrar necesidad socioeconómica.</li>
                                                                    <li>Promedio acumulado igual o mayor a 85.</li>
                                                                    <li>Obtener 1,300* puntos en la Prueba de Aptitud Académica (PAA). Solo para alumnas de primer ingreso.</li>
                                                                    <li>Ser alumna becada, con al menos un 60% de beca.</li>
                                                                    <li>Llenar la solicitud de postulación.</li>
                                                                    <li>Currículum Vitae.</li>
                                                                    <li>Elaborar un ensayo no mayor a 2 cuartillas, en el que expongas por qué deseas obtener este apoyo de hospedaje.</li>
                                                                    <li>Acudir a la sesión de entrevistas programada previa cita.</li>
                                                                </ul></div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paragraph-contactosplan2396">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                <div class="white">
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                <div class="content-description">
                                                                    <div class="field-content">Dra. Carolina Morales            carolina.morales@itesm.mx
                                                                        Lic. Andree Zinelli.               mandree.zinelli@gmail.com
                                                                        Fondos Externos                  fondosexte.mty@itesm.mx

                                                                    </div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="paragraph-fechasplan2396">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                    <div class="white">
                                                        <div class="container">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                    <div class="content-description">
                                                                        <div class="field-content"><p>Convocatoria:</p>
                                                                        <p>Del 2 al 20&nbsp;de Abril</p>
                                                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                                                        <p>Entrevistas:<br>
                                                                        Primera semana de Mayo</p>
                                                                        <p>Resultados :<br>
                                                                        Entre el 11 y 15 de Mayo</p>
                                                                    </div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--FIN -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: que hijo estas buscando?instentastes usando el .find("la clase o el id")

Comment: $('.view-content').find().each(function () { ¿asi? ya lo intente y aun no funciona

Comment: en el find tienes que colocar la clase de los hijos que andas buscando

Comment: intente usarlo asi $(".view-content" ).find( ".views-row-odd" ).each(function () { pero sigue sin imprimirme nada en el console.log

Comment: puedes colocar el html de como quedaria con los hijos? es para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: listo, puse muy poco por el limite que me da de caracteres en html aqui, cabe recordar que ese html me lo trae desde ajax, despues de que ya cargo la pagina

Comment: que es esto #edit-field-campus-pro-target-id? un div que engloba todo el html que colocastes arriba? es que no lo veo en el html que colocas

Comment: Hola Rodrigo.  ¿Puede ser que el problema no esté ahí sino en el evento "change"? ¿El INPUT se usás tiene el id "edit-field-campus-pro-target-id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ocupes `document` como selector global para eventos, utiliza `body`

**NOTA:** `children()` te captura los hijos inmediatos no te lee los hijos de los hijos

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('body').on('change', '#edit-field-campus-pro-target-id' ,function() {
      // cambie de posición la variable 'numero' para que cada vez que se ejecute el 'change' cuente desde 0
      var numero=0;
      $('.view-content').children().each(function () {
         numero=numero+1;
         console.log(numero);
    });
});
});

function addP(){
  var pElement = document.createElement('p');
  pElement.innerText = "Párrafo generado";
  $('.view-content').append(pElement);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Como no agregaste el elemento "#edit-field-campus-pro-target-id" para efectos de prueba asumiré que es un checkbox y cada que cambie de estado se imprimirá la cantidad de elementos</p>
<label for"edit-field-campus-pro-target-id">Contar Elementos</label>
<input id="edit-field-campus-pro-target-id" type="checkbox" >

<button onclick="addP()">Agregar párrafo</button>
<div class="view-content"></div>
```

Comment: Por alguna razon sigue sin funcionarme esto en mi codigo :(, simplemente no me imprime nada.

Comment: @RodrigoLoy haz un duplicado lo mas exacto posible de tu código en https://codepen.io/  o en https://jsfiddle.net/ de forma que todos podamos verlo funcionando mal y podamos ayudarte a corregirlo

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que tenias mal el evento, el evento change quedaría así:

```
$("#edit-field-campus-pro-target-id").on('change', function() {
  var numero = 0;
  $('.view-content').children().each(function () {
     numero=numero+1;
     console.log(numero);
  });

});
```

Puedes ver funcionando y veras como en el console.log() muestra la cantidad de hijos a medida que va recorriendo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').formSelect();
});

$("#edit-field-campus-pro-target-id").on('change', function() {
  var numero = 0;
  $('.view-content').children(".views-row-odd").each(function () {
     numero=numero+1;
     console.log(numero);
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="input-field col s12" >
  <select id="edit-field-campus-pro-target-id">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-odd">
    <div class="field--item">
      <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-titulo-imagen-cont paragraph--view-mode--default" id="federal-plus-loan">
        <div class="white">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column-left border-right flex-center" style="height: 350px;">
                <div class="content-columns">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="text-left">
                      <div class="field field--name-field-adm-titulo field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">Casas de asistencia del CEMYD </div>
                      <div class="field field--name-field-adm-descripcion field--item">
                      <p>Tiene como labor social proporcionar hospedaje a estudiantes mujeres talentosas y con limitantes económicas. Como parte de su filosofía y en apoyo a los valores que el Tec promueve en sus alumnos, el CEMYD enfatiza en la práctica de competencias ciudadanas y desarrollo profesional, así como también crear conciencia de la responsabilidad de retribuir el apoyo recibido por este Club.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                      <i class="material-icons collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#acordeon2396" href="#acordeon2396" style="color: #C42129"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column-right imagen" style="height: 350px;">
              <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="content-imagen" style="background:#212121;">
                  <div class="field field--name-field-adm-imagen field--type-image field--label-hidden field--item">
                    <img src="/sites/default/files/foto3.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt="FEDERAL PLUS LOAN" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" style="height: 350px;">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse" id="acordeon2396">
            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-cont-tabs paragraph--view-mode--default">
              <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active" style="border-bottom-width: 54px;">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-caracteristicasplan2396">CARACTERÍSTICAS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li style="border-bottom-width: 54px;">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-beneficiosplan2396">REQUISITOS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li style="border-bottom-width: 54px;">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-contactosplan2396">CONTACTOS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li style="border-bottom-width: 54px; display: none;">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#paragraph-fechasplan2396">FECHAS</a>
                  </li>
                 </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="paragraph-caracteristicasplan2396">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                <div class="white">
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                <div class="content-description">
                                                                    <div class="field-content"><ul><li>Apoyo de hospedaje</li>
                                                                    <li>Aplica solo para mujeres</li>
                                                                </ul></div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade " id="paragraph-beneficiosplan2396">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                <div class="white">
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                <div class="content-description">
                                                                    <div class="field-content"><ul><li>Admisión al Tecnológico de Monterrey, Campus Monterrey</li>
                                                                    <li>Demostrar necesidad socioeconómica.</li>
                                                                    <li>Promedio acumulado igual o mayor a 85.</li>
                                                                    <li>Obtener 1,300* puntos en la Prueba de Aptitud Académica (PAA). Solo para alumnas de primer ingreso.</li>
                                                                    <li>Ser alumna becada, con al menos un 60% de beca.</li>
                                                                    <li>Llenar la solicitud de postulación.</li>
                                                                    <li>Currículum Vitae.</li>
                                                                    <li>Elaborar un ensayo no mayor a 2 cuartillas, en el que expongas por qué deseas obtener este apoyo de hospedaje.</li>
                                                                    <li>Acudir a la sesión de entrevistas programada previa cita.</li>
                                                                </ul></div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paragraph-contactosplan2396">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                <div class="white">
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                <div class="content-description">
                                                                    <div class="field-content">Dra. Carolina Morales            carolina.morales@itesm.mx
                                                                        Lic. Andree Zinelli.               mandree.zinelli@gmail.com
                                                                        Fondos Externos                  fondosexte.mty@itesm.mx

                                                                    </div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="paragraph-fechasplan2396">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="paragraph paragraph--type--adm-columnas paragraph--view-mode--default">
                                                    <div class="white">
                                                        <div class="container">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 ">
                                                                    <div class="content-description">
                                                                        <div class="field-content"><p>Convocatoria:</p>
                                                                        <p>Del 2 al 20&nbsp;de Abril</p>
                                                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                                                        <p>Entrevistas:<br>
                                                                        Primera semana de Mayo</p>
                                                                        <p>Resultados :<br>
                                                                        Entre el 11 y 15 de Mayo</p>
                                                                    </div>                                                                                        </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--FIN -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿pero porque el evento no es change? #edit-field-campus-pro-target-id no es un boton, es un select ¿o esto tambien aplica para select?

Comment: ahh ok ya lo cambio perdona es que en el html no esta indicado ya lo edito

Comment: si perdón, justo te lo iba a especificar cuando me respondiste esto jeje

Comment: Listo prueba a ver

Comment: mm no, sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Esta respuesta no es correcta. Obviamente no se adapta al ejemplo, y los nuevos elementos que se generen dinámicamente en el contenedor padre no mantendrán el manejador del evento indicado

Comment: @RodrigoLoy el evento change tienes que colocarlo en el success despues de armar el contenido, lo probastes así?

Comment: ¿te refieres en el ajax verdad? no no puedo probarlo ahi  porque yo no tengo el manejo de ese ajax, drupal genera el ajax por medio de una view, no puedo ver ese codigo

Comment: si, la idea es crear el evento luego de que el contenido se genere, no antes porque sino no lo hará, si colocas el evento change en el document ready estas creando un evento a un elemento que una no existe, entiendes?

Comment: lo comprendo, estaba consiente que ese es mi problema, por eso preguntaba que como hacerle con contenido dinamico, porque se que no estaba creada en la pagina desde el principio

Comment: si claro, pero lo ideal seria llamar al evento despues del ajax, pero si no tienes acceso a el es muy dificil, intentastes con la otra respuesta?